# CheckBoxTreeTableCell Select All Children Under Parent Event

Tags: java, treeview, javafx-8

I'm trying to select all child check boxes from a parent root. The action is invoked when the parent check box is selected.

Here's the pseudo/modified/shortened set up with scenebuilder:

```
@FXML
private TreeTableView<Info> testTable;
@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Info, Boolean> checkBoxCol;
```

Model:

```
public class Info{
    private final BooleanProperty onHold;

    public Info(){
        this.onHold = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    }
    public Boolean getOnHold(){
        return onHold.get();
    }
    public void setOnHold(Boolean onHold) {
        this.onHold.set(onHold);
    }
    public BooleanProperty onHoldProperty(){
        return onHold;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    checkBoxCol.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory("onHold"));
    checkBoxCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn(checkBoxCol));
```

End Result would look like this (when parent nodes are clicked):

[image]

I tried onEditCommit/start/cancel, but those seem to only affect the cell and not the checkboxes. I am not exactly sure how to get a listener for only the parent nodes so that it can check all values underneath (if they have children). If it's too difficult to only allow just the parent nodes to have the listener, then all the checkbox can have listeners and I can simply check if there are children with:`node.getChildren().size()`

Comment: If you want to attach listener to checkbox then go to class that represents this checkbox and look at its methods. There you will find method just for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to manage this entirely in the model.

The `TreeTableView` consists of a `TreeItem<Info>` root with a bunch of descendent nodes. Just arrange that whenever you create the tree items, you add a listener to the properties:

```
private TreeItem<Info> createTreeItem(Info info) {
    TreeItem<Info> item = new TreeItem<>(info);
    info.onHoldProperty().addListener((obs, wasOnHold, isNowOnHold) -> {
        if (isNowOnHold) {
            item.getChildren().forEach(child -> child.getValue().setOnHold(true));
        }
    });
    return item ;
}
```

Complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreeTableViewInheritableCheckBoxes extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TreeTableView<Info> table = new TreeTableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);

        TreeTableColumn<Info, Boolean> infoCol = new TreeTableColumn<>("Info");
        infoCol.setPrefWidth(200);

        infoCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().onHoldProperty());
        infoCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn(infoCol));
        table.getColumns().add(infoCol);

        TreeItem<Info> root = createTreeItem(new Info());

        buildTree(root, 0);

        table.setRoot(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(table), 250, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void buildTree(TreeItem<Info> parent, int depth) {
        if (depth > 2) return ;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            TreeItem<Info> item = createTreeItem(new Info());
            parent.getChildren().add(item);
            buildTree(item, depth + 1);
        }
    }

    private TreeItem<Info> createTreeItem(Info info) {
        TreeItem<Info> item = new TreeItem<>(info);
        info.onHoldProperty().addListener((obs, wasOnHold, isNowOnHold) -> {
            if (isNowOnHold) {
                item.getChildren().forEach(child -> child.getValue().setOnHold(true));
            }
        });
        return item ;
    }

    public static class Info {
        private final BooleanProperty onHold;

        public Info(){
            this.onHold = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        }
        public Boolean getOnHold(){
            return onHold.get();
        }
        public void setOnHold(Boolean onHold) {
            this.onHold.set(onHold);
        }
        public BooleanProperty onHoldProperty(){
            return onHold;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You sire, are like the javafx fairy-godfather in stackoverflow. You save us from aspirin and extra caffeine! :]